# R no methods found when calling methods(sma)

Tags: r, oop

I'm using `sma` from package Smooth and it's all working fine. Just curious why when I call `methods(sma)` it doesn't give any methods:

```
> methods(sma)
no methods found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`methods` function returns:

> List all      available methods for a S3 and S4 generic function, or all methods for 
>   an S3 or S4 class.

hence there are no such methods available for `sma` function.
Please compare with e.g. `plot`.

```
head(methods(plot), 20)
```

Output:

```
 [1] "plot,ANY,ANY-method"         "plot,ca.jo,missing-method"   "plot,ca.po,missing-method"   "plot,color,ANY-method"      
 [5] "plot,timeDate,ANY-method"    "plot,ur.df,missing-method"   "plot,ur.ers,missing-method"  "plot,ur.kpss,missing-method"
 [9] "plot,ur.pp,missing-method"   "plot,ur.sp,missing-method"   "plot,ur.za,missing-method"   "plot.acf"                   
[13] "plot.ACF"                    "plot.ar"                     "plot.Arima"                  "plot.arma"                  
[17] "plot.armasubsets"            "plot.augPred"                "plot.bats"                   "plot.chobTA"
```